# Does MongoDB Scala driver have any equivalent to the explain() function in the JavaScript interface?

Tags: mongodb, scala

Does MongoDB Scala driver have any equivalent to the `explain()` function in the JavaScript interface?

I'm wondering what the MongoDB Scala driver does with a query like this:

```
collection.find(
  and(geoWithinBox("geometry", bbox.swLon, bbox.swLat, bbox.neLon, bbox.neLat),
    equal("properties.foo", "abc"),
    exists("properties.bar")))
  .limit(100)
```

MongoDB does not seem to be using the geospatial index I created and I'm trying to figure out why.  Rather, it seems to be scanning every document.  At least that's what I noticed when I tried `explain` with this JS query in MongoShell:

```
{$and: [{"geometry": {$geoWithin: {$box: [ [-78,40],[-76,41] ] }}},
        {$and: [{"properties.foo": {$eq: "abc"}},
                {"properties.bar": {$exists: 1}}
               ]
        }
       ]
}
```

(I didn't have nested-`and`s in the first version of the JS immediately above.  I was just trying different things to see if they triggered use of the geospatial index.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on current MongoDB Scala driver [v1.1.0](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.1/) and current [MongoDB v3.2](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production).

Currently there is no cursor explain() function via the Scala driver. This is because `explain` has been determined to be not a normal use-case for a driver. I would recommend to use the [Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/client/) for debugging query index usages. See [MongoDB driver spec](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/crud/crud.rst#q--a) for more info.

However you can still use [runCommand](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) to get explain output. For example of [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) query in Mongo Shell :

```js
db.collection.find({
    "geometries":{
        $geoWithin:{
            $box:[[-78,40], [-76, 41]]
        }
    }
}).explain()
```

You can do the same using command in Scala like below:

```java
val command = Document("explain" -> Document("find"->"collection", 
                        "filter"->Document("geometries"->Document(
                                "$geoWithin"->Document(
                                     "$box"->Seq(Seq(-78, 40), Seq(-76, 41))
                                  )
                            )
                        )
                    )
               )
val observable = db.runCommand(command).printHeadResult()
```

Or for aggregation queries

```java
  db.runCommand(
    Document(
      "aggregate" -> "collection",
      "pipeline" -> List[Document]( ... ),
      "explain" -> true
    )
  )
```

Worth mentioning that only [2d](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/) geospatial index supports [$box](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/) operator. Make sure that you have the right index for field `geometries`.

Also, by default queries are constructed implicitly with `AND`, so you don't have to specify [$and](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) explicitly. Your example can be shorten to :

```js
db.collection.find({"geometry": {$geoWithin: {$box: [[-78,40],[-76,41]] }},
                    "properties.foo" : "abc", 
                    "properties.bar": {$exists:true}
                   })
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I changed the box query to use polygon so it could use the 2dsphere index.  I did not know about runCommand.  You have been a great help.